# Traversing through linkedlist

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

For a school assignment we're asked to make a linkedlist using data structures in c++.
Now we've never ever touched c++ (only dabbled a bit in JAVA) so the assignment is a bit overwhelming.

I'm having a bit of trouble traversing and cout'ing my linkedlist (assuming that the way i've created the linked list isn't horribly flawed).

Given the following code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>

    using namespace std;

    struct getallenlijst {
            int getal1;
            int getal2;
            int getal3;
            getallenlijst* next;
            };

    int main() {
            srand(time(NULL)); //Create random nummer, seed is time voor randomize.


    getallenlijst* n;               //maak pointer aan voor n. Maken hiermee nieuwe structs aan.
    getallenlijst* t;               //maak pointer aan voor t. Linken hiermee de boel aan elkaar.
    getallenlijst* h;               //maak hiermee een start punt.

    n = new getallenlijst;          //maak nieuwe struct aan.
    n->getal1 = rand();             //vul met data.
    n->getal2 = rand();
    n->getal3 = rand();

    t = n;          //definieer t voor linken van lists.
    h = n;          //definieer h zodat we altijd terug naar start kunnen.

    n = new getallenlijst;
    n->getal1 = rand();
    n->getal2 = rand();
    n->getal3 = rand();

    t->next = n; // verplaats t naar voren van oude struct.
    t = n; //verplaats t weer naar de next in struct.

    n = new getallenlijst;
    n->getal1 = rand();
    n->getal2 = rand();
    n->getal3 = rand();

    t->next = n; // verplaats t naar voren van oude struct.

    n = new getallenlijst;
    t = n; //verplaats t weer naar de next in struct.
    n->getal1 = rand();
    n->getal2 = rand();
    n->getal3 = rand();

    t->next = n; // verplaats t naar voren van oude struct.

    n = new getallenlijst;
    t = n; //verplaats t weer naar de next in struct.
    n->getal1 = rand();
    n->getal2 = rand();
    n->getal3 = rand();

    t->next = n;            //verplaats t weer.
    n->next = NULL;         //Eindig lijst.



//Loop om getallen uit te printen.
getallenlijst *current = n;
while( current != NULL ) {
cout << (*current).getal1 << endl;
cout << (*current).getal2 << endl;
cout << (*current).getal3 << endl;
current = current->next;
}

        delete n;
                return 0;
}
```

I'd expect that using the while loop i'd traverse throught the structs (list) and cout all the integers that i've created. But it actually only seems to show the integer values for the first list.

I'm sorry that a lot of the declarations and comments are in Dutch, i never thought i'd end up posting this and asking a question.

Anyone care to give me a nod in the proper direction ? (i think it's because in my first list the next pointer could be empty but i'm at a loss how to resolve that)

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Added a missing piece of my code that didn't get copied&pasted over.

Comment: You are not updating t correctly after the second node. You need to set t= n before you allocated a new node. You did it correctly for the second node and then something bad happened.

Comment: `so the assignment is a bit overwhelming` -- That is because what you read in your data structures book is best implemented in languages such as Java.  Trying to implement this in C++ not only requires you to know about the data structure, but the intricacies of C++ memory management.  So you have two mountains to climb (and I have yet see a beginner write a proper C++ linked list class correctly, with no bugs and no pitfalls).

Comment: @Pemdas Allright, thanks ! i moved the t = n declarations to before i created a new node. But it still only cout's out 3 numbers. Am i missing something else ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Unfortunately we don't really have class. They just gave us a book and told us to make this assignment and then we get an assesment about it the next week. Part of some "new" learning style they're trying. ;(

Comment: You don't show how you print the list, so I don't know

Comment: @Pemdas Yeah sorry i just noticed that myself ! Just updated it.

Comment: @Jdeboer -- Then you might as well look at a working example and figure out how it works.  Otherwise probably the only help you'll get is for someone to write the code for you as an answer if all you have is a week.  Like I said, this is not trivial, and just having an assignment thrown at you like this with no experience is a losing proposition.  But one thing -- it would help a lot of you used more descriptive variable names.  Names like `h`, `t`, etc. do not convey a lot of information, making the code hard to understand.

Comment: you need set current to the head of the list, which you define as h not n

Comment: You are also leaking memory. You only delete the last node allocated.

Comment: @Pemdas my god, you're a hero. I totally missed that, thank you ! I'll look into the memory leak and how to solve that thanks for that one too ! :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I definately get that. I feel dirty for putting the question up in the first place but i was so stuck and feeling lost. I'm trying to do most of this by myself and by looking at examples in the book or online. I feel like sometimes people (be it on stackexchange or a teacher) help clear things up that i get stuck on. And again, apologies for the unclear declarations. I never thought i would have to share this but then again i guess part of doing a good job coding is clearing all that up in the first place. Flagged your post as usefull as a thank you.